# Break the props to next line for a component in react

Tags: reactjs, prettier

I am using Prettier and trying to format on save and break the lines of my props from

```
<A key={id} image={avatar} username={username} />
```

to this when i save.

```
<A 
  key={id} 
  image={avatar} 
  username={username} />
```

Comment: If the line is long enough, it will be broken up into multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `react/jsx-first-prop-new-line` rule for this.

Reference - https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-first-prop-new-line.md

Comment: how can I set this all ,  I am a begginer